# Triangle drawn using css borders appears on the top of the text

Tags: html, css

Triangle next to my text is vertically aligned towards the top instead of being in same level as the text.

It looks like,

[image]

Plunker code is [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/KeestwsxGNpzF2V2sjEE?p=preview).

My css for triangle is,

```
.arrow-down {
   width: 0; 
   height: 0; 
   border-left: 10px solid transparent;
   border-right: 10px solid transparent;
   border-top: 10px solid #000;   
 }
```

Note: Alternatively, i tried to display a triangle using the unicode `\25BC` but it didn't appear.

```
<span class="triangle"></span>

 .triangle{
   display: inline-block;
   width: 20px;
   height: 20px;
   content : '\25BC';
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting `display: inline-block;` for `.arrow-down` will fix issue by allowing inline element to take defined height and width:

```css
/* Styles go here */

.arrow-down {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 10px solid transparent;
  border-right: 10px solid transparent;
  border-top: 10px solid #000;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  Level One Menu
  <span class="arrow-down"></span>
</body>

</html>
```

**Note explained**

It does not work because `content` has only pseudo-elements `:before` and `:after`

```css
.triangle:after {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  content: '\25BC';
}
```

```html
<span class="triangle"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add `display: inline-block;` to your style of arrow.